# Does an app's bundle ID change after App Transfer in the developer program and itunes connect?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, developer-program

I have successfully received a transferred app as per Apple's documentation on transfers: [App transfers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html)

However when uploading a new version of this app I receive [this warning](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1726/_index.html) that is caused because the app is now under a different team ID:

> Potential Loss of Keychain Access. The previous version of software
>   has an application-identifier value of 'A1B2C3D4E5.com.company.app'
>   and the new version of software being submitted has an
>   application-identifier of '5E4D3C2B1A.com.company.app'. This will
>   result in a loss of keychain access.

Does that mean that the app's bundle id has changed to include the new team ID?  The error message seems to indicate that it has.

However in itunes connect the app's bundle id still shows without the team id as:

```
com.company.app
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes the app identifier changes and no the bundle remains in your scenario. Unless you copied the information wrong from the portal, 5E4D3C2B1A.com.company.app is what you’ll ship next iteration.

When you submit and the app goes to sale, only the Team ID part of the app identifier will change and you’ll have the one time loss of keychain data the app stored.

This could be minor or major depending on how the app was designed.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014135-CH1-A_ONE_TIME_LOSS_IN_KEYCHAIN_DATA_WILL_OCCUR_IF_YOU_SWITCH_YOUR_APP_ID_PREFIX

If you have thousands of users or can’t be sure you are safe after talking to the previous Dev or inspecting the code, you might burn one of your paid support incidents with Apple to review the code and be sure you’re safe to go with the change.

Comment: Hi thanks, yes I know the team ID changes and we lose previous keychain data.  But that wasn't the question.  The question was does the app's bundle ID change, yes or no?  I know about the keychain and its not a problem.  But if the bundle ID changes that will cause other problems - this is what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: Edited to make clear only the team part changes.

Comment: Thanks, sorry if I'm not quite understanding yet.  Are the app identifier and the bundle id two different things?  In this question I'm only trying to find out if its changed or not (since we're only allowed to ask one question per post). Heres my other question on SO asking about the problem I'm seeing after app transfer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45384982/325727